# If all maps from $X$ to $X$ continuous, then $X$ has the discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

I am reading a book called Algebra in the Stone-Cech Compactification written by Neil Hindman, Dona Strauss.

There is a Corollary 2.3. in his book that he said: Let $X$ be any topological space. The following statements are equivalent.
(c) For all $f \in X_{X}$, $f$ is continuous.
(d) X is discrete.

But I cannot understand why (c) implies (d) because if X is trivial. That is, only $\emptyset$ and $X$ is open in $X$. So for every $x \in X$ and $f(x)$, $f(x)$ neighborhood is $X$, so every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ can find $f[U]\subset X$. So every function of $f$ is continuous but $X$ is not discrete. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, as stated the result is not correct for precisely the reason you mention. However, on page $38$ (just after Definition $2.1$) the authors write:

> We did not include any separation axioms in the definitions given above. However, all of our applications involve Hausdorff spaces. So we shall be assuming throughout, except in Chapter 7, that all hypothesized topological spaces are Hausdorff.

Given the implicit assumption of Hausdorff-ness (also called $T_2$-ness), the exercise is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have thought two hours in this question but forgot this sentence. I should have read it more closely. Really thank you so much!